# How to remote profile using JProfiler for JVM that was started by nobody user?

Tags: linux, jprofiler

On my remore Linux server I have Java app that is running as 'nobody' user. I connect JProfiler through SSH Tunnel and I am able to view JVM when swith user to root (via su) after SSH Tunnel login as normal user. But when I click Open I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Usually there are no login credentials for user "nobody", so it would not be possible to switch to the user "nobody". Can you start the application as some other user? If not, you have to add the `-agentpath` VM parameter for profiling to the java invocation as given by Session->Integration Wizards->New Remote Integration.